# Android Notification lights not working

Tags: java, android

I am having some trouble with making the LED flashing with a notification as created below.

```
Notification n = new Notification();
n.icon = R.drawable.icon;
n.tickerText = title+": "+message;
n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
try {
    n.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Reported to be not present in all versions
}
try {
    n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    n.ledARGB = 0xff3fabff;
    n.ledOnMS = 300;
    n.ledOffMS = 1000;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Not sure since what API level
}
if (alert) {
    n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
}
Intent i = new Intent(Plugin.NOTIFY);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, i, 0);
n.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, title, message, pi);
nm.notify(0, n);
```

On my Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.3 everything is working but the lights, which are working for all other apps, though. I have been using the app for weeks now and the lights never flashed, regardless of if the device is connected to a computer or not. So I assume that I must be missing something elementary here (is there another permission in addition to VIBRATE?) and I hope that you guys have a hint for me.

Comment: I would recommend that you switch to `Notification.Builder` or `NotificationCompat.Builder`, to make sure that you are setting the LED support up correctly.